# Possible RegexP_Filter error in Sphinx?

Tags: regex, sphinx

I'm doing something like this:

- Replacing Upper case Acronyms that are also words (e.g. HI=Hawaii) as upper_$Accronym for future searching.
- Doing so on pattern matches.

So for HI above for instance I'd do:

```
regexp_filter = (HI)(\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,3}?(Manufacturing)\b) => upper_\1\2
```

I used \2 because as per

```
https://regex101.com/r/uZ4zK1/1
```

The second capture group gives me the leading space needed so the term (in theory) becomes

```
upper_HI Manufacturing
```

My issue is that somewhere in the process "HI" is recognized ONLY as "Hi".

Any of the following match the indexed record:

```
select  Name from idx_Test WHERE (MATCH('"upper_Hi Manufacturing"'))
select  Name from idx_Test WHERE (MATCH('"upper_Hi" "Manufacturing"'))
select  Name from idx_Test WHERE (MATCH('"upper_Hi"'))
```

all do the following fail:

```
select  Name from idx_Test WHERE (MATCH('"upper_HI Manufacturing"'))
select  Name from idx_Test WHERE (MATCH('"upper_HI" "Manufacturing"'))
select  Name from idx_Test WHERE (MATCH('"upper_HI"'))
```

Even if I explicitly force the "HI" in:

```
regexp_filter = (HI)(\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,3}?(Manufacturing)\b) => upper_HI\2
```

I get the same error.

Comment: Problem seems related to sphinx, regex seems fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember the regex_filter is applied to the **query** as well.

So you should search

```
select Name from idx_Test WHERE MATCH('"HI Manufacturing"')
```

You dont need to apply the transformation yourself. In fact in your example, it would be 'double' applied, once by you, once by sphinx, turning it into `MATCH('"upper_upper_hi manufacturing"')` which is why it doesnt match.

A mixed case 'Hi' sort of works, because the regex filter does NOT fire. Remember regex's ARE case sensitive.

It still matches, because charset_table makes matching not case-sensitive.

Comment: You also add \b at the beginning of the regular expression to avoid double replacements.

Comment: Interesting. So converting 'HI' conditionally to 'upper_HI' means now I can MATCH('HI') and only get matches where a)  does not = 'hi' and b) where = HI but not with the pattern I indicated. I had thought it meant I had to now search for upper_HI. Even better if so let me do some testing and report back.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match (HI|Hi|hi) then you can either explicitly define each, or better yet add a flag to trigger case-insensitive matching: `(?i)`

```
regexp_filter = (?i)(HI)(\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,3}?(Manufacturing)\b) => upper_\1\2
```

Comment: Note, that sphinx is not 'based' on Mysql really. Its more designed to look 'like' mysql, for familarities sake. Those queries wont work.

Comment: Thanks @barryhunter - I've removed the statements